Am I buying back my same covered call I wrote?
So I understand that a recommended strategy when selling Covered Calls is to buy it back before it expires.
What I'm unclear on is am I buying back the exact Covered Call I wrote? Or is it someone else's covered call that I'm purchasing?

Does it matter?

Does it matter?  Sometimes, people want to understand how things work.

You're "buying" someone else's contract, which in reality means that the original contract you "sold" is being reassigned to the party you're buying from. (In reality you're not really buying or selling anything, it's just contract assignments changing hands).
It's possible, but highly unlikely, that your "buy" is matched up with the exact same counterparty as the original contract, in which case the entire contract just goes away. It would be like paying for your coffee in New York with a $5 bill, then getting that same bill back as change in Los Angeles.
But there's no need to concern yourself with these details - the exchange uses the Options Clearing Corporation (OCC) to recognize that your position has been cancelled, and you no longer have any obligation for either transaction.

Hmm.. so firstly I sell a covered call contract, which means the initial buyer (buyer A) could potentially buy my shares if the strike price is hit. So far so good.
Now I want to close. I then buy someone else's contract (person B), and suddenly I'm off the hook to relinquish my shares to buyer A - who originally bought my contract.
Is this because the new contract I bought from person B immediately goes to buyer A? (and thus Buyer A is still in a position to receive 100 shares, only from someone else?)

@mcs You can think about it that way if you want to. But in reality, they just track a +1 in one column, a 0 in another column, and a -1 in yet a third column. Parties are only assigned if options are exercised.

@DavidSchwartz thanks. But what I'm unclear on is that the buyer was originally going to be calling my 100 shares during assignment. Now that I've 'bought back' the contract, who's shares will they now call during assignment?

Someone else who sold you the contract you bought, or who sold a different call that got passed around. The OCC takes care of all of those assignments.  It's largely irrelevant who the counterparty is on exchange transactions.

also, options rarely get executed early - it's almost always better to buy/sell the contract than to exercise early.

@mcs Whoever you did a "buy to close", you paid someone else to take over that obligation from you. That someone else has to fulfill the contract if the option is exercised unless they also pay someone else to do it.

When you buy-to-close a short call, you are buying the exact call contract that you sold. However, it's highly unlikely that you are buying it back from the original counterparty who sold it to you.
As expiration approaches, you have three choices:

If your contract is out-of-the-money, you could let it expire.

It's in-the-money and the sale price is acceptable (the strike place plus the premium received), accept assignment.

If your intent is to close your existing covered call and open a new one, the most efficient way to do this would be 'rolling' the position via a spread order.



If you previously wrote a December 2024 call option for Smokeshifter Inc. at a strike price of $50, then you can buy back a December 2024 call option for Smokeshifter Inc. at a strike price of $50 to close your position.
All such options are fungible (interchangeable) so it doesn't matter whether it's the same precise option or not.

Right. but if I buy it back, who's shares will the Buyer of the option be calling? ie since originally the buyer is calling my 100 shares, but now they wouldn't be anymore.

Somebody else's shares but not yours.
